# How do I breed two NFTs on Solana?

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, nft, solana-cli, cnft

I would like to breed NFTs on the Solana blockchain. Does Metaplex offer a feature for breeding two NFTs, or can we create a custom Rust program for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - A code snippet or any reference as help would be most appreciated from which I can get started.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native 'breeding' function in metaplex, but you can check out this anchor program for [reference](https://github.com/DappioLab/nft-breeding).

Comment: Hi @Madhav -  Did you work on this repo? basically I'm stuck in a problem for a while.